Postgres pg_dump exceed diskspace
I have been trying to run a pg_dump on a database that is showing 40gb in pg_database_size(),
I am aware that pg_database_size() is not the best correlation to the end dump file size.
I have tried to pipe the pg_dump with xz but is taking more than 1TB of diskspace, but checking the dump file created after erroring out is less than 4gb.
What would be the next best approach ?
have tried to use the following
pg_dump -Fc -Z0 | xz -9 dump.custom.xz
pg_dump-Fc -Z9 -f file.dump
Is there anything i should be increasing i.e diskspace to make it work.
As this Postgres RDS is on AWS i am also considering to take a snapshot and manage it via terraform.

A 40GB database, including indexes and overhead, doesn’t take 1TB of space when you make a backup. Especially since you can compress the backup. There is something else going on but you didn’t share any information at all. Could you share the exact commands for measuring the size and making the backup?

the command that i used was pg_dump -Fc -Z0 | xz -9 dump.custom.xz

even when i tr to do pg_dump-Fc -Z9 -f file.dump ( it is the same error with not enough disk space ) , as i have said before i dont think pg_database_size is a good indication to what the backup size is meant to be

What do you get when you run psql -c "select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(current_user));"  You might be checking the wrong database and the pg_dump-Fc -Z9 -f file.dump command you showed would assume you're connecting as a db user named after the current system user, to a database named after that user, unless you have environment variables set up to override that.

@Zegarek , ive removed -h -d -p in the pg_dump command as i thought it wouldnt matter to this question but happy to include them

Do the dump without -Fc.  If the dump is small, then you know the problem is with -Fc.  If it is still large, then look at the contents of the large file/stream to see if that is informative.

Why do you feel the need to use xz in the first place? Just use pg_dump by itself, it will output gzip with compression turned on.
